# Declaration or statement expected jquery error

Tags: jquery, html, error-handling

the code is working in browser, but when i'm open the file, there has 1 error..
im trying to solve this.. but i can't, please help me..

```js
function showMessage(mode) {
 var divMessage = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" +
  "Berhasil <strong>" + mode.toUpperCase() + "</strong> pertanyaan" +
  "</div>";
 $(divMessage)
  .prependTo(".ini")
  .delay(2000)
  .slideUp("slow");
}
```

Comment: what does mode return, if you e.g. alert(mode)?

Comment: and is the error really caused in this function? did you check the line, what is the full error message?